# SQL Server 2008, insert date when use case when

Tags: sql-server

I have this table

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ COMPANY ║ NAME  ║       DATE        ║
╠═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╣
║ A       ║ Roger ║ 4/17/2015 0:00:00 ║
║ B       ║ Larry ║ 4/9/2015 0:00:00  ║
║ C       ║ Paul  ║ 4/9/2015 0:00:00  ║
║ D       ║ Scott ║ 4/24/2015 0:00:00 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

I would like to make it so that the table looks like

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ COMPANY ║       Roger       ║      Larry       ║       Paul       ║       Scott       ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ A       ║ 4/17/2015 0:00:00 ║ -                ║ -                ║ -                 ║
║ B       ║ -                 ║ 4/9/2015 0:00:00 ║ -                ║ -                 ║
║ C       ║ -                 ║ -                ║ 4/9/2015 0:00:00 ║ -                 ║
║ D       ║ -                 ║ -                ║ -                ║ 4/24/2015 0:00:00 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

So I tried this but it's not inserting the date, any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (company),
    [Roger]  = (CASE WHEN [str_lastname] = 'Roger' THEN 'date' ELSE '-' END),
    [Larry]  = (CASE WHEN [str_lastname] = 'Larry' THEN 'date' ELSE '-' END),
    [Paul]  = (CASE WHEN [str_lastname] = 'Paul' THEN 'date' ELSE '-' END),
    [Scott]  = (CASE WHEN [str_lastname] = 'Scott' THEN 'date' ELSE '-' END)
FROM 
    #temp1
```

It inserts the word date but not the actual date from the column.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: use [date]. 'date' is a string

Comment: You also need to not use '-' in the ELSE or you will get a conversion error.

Comment: If it inserts `"date"` its not a date column, it probably should be with `NULL` instead of `-`

Comment: Are you trying to change the table structure or just return data?  IF you're just trying to return data, take a look at the `UNPIVOT` command.

Comment: What will happen when new names will come tomorrow will columns grow?

Comment: Thank you that works, using  [date] and the took out the else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @stuff TABLE 
  ( 
     company  CHAR(1) NULL, 
     NAME     VARCHAR(20) NULL, 
     somedate DATETIME NULL 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @stuff 
            (company, 
             NAME, 
             somedate) 
VALUES     ('A', 
            'Roger', 
            '04/17/2015') 

INSERT INTO @stuff 
            (company, 
             NAME, 
             somedate) 
VALUES     ('B', 
            'Larry', 
            '04/9/2015') 

INSERT INTO @stuff 
            (company, 
             NAME, 
             somedate) 
VALUES     ('C', 
            'Paul', 
            '04/9/2015') 

INSERT INTO @stuff 
            (company, 
             NAME, 
             somedate) 
VALUES     ('D', 
            'Scott', 
            '04/24/2015') 

SELECT DISTINCT ( company ), 
                [Roger] = ( CASE 
                              WHEN[name] = 'Roger' THEN Cast( 
                              [somedate] AS VARCHAR) 
                              ELSE '-' 
                            END ), 
                [Larry] = ( CASE 
                              WHEN[name] = 'Larry' THEN Cast( 
                              [somedate] AS VARCHAR) 
                              ELSE '-' 
                            END ), 
                [Paul] = ( CASE 
                             WHEN[name] = 'Paul' THEN Cast([somedate] AS VARCHAR 
                                                      ) 
                             ELSE '-' 
                           END ), 
                [Scott] = ( CASE 
                              WHEN[name] = 'Scott' THEN Cast( 
                              [somedate] AS VARCHAR) 
                              ELSE '-' 
                            END ) 
FROM   @stuff
```

Produces this:
[image: SQL Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COMPANY,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN NAME = 'Roger' THEN CONVERT(varchar, [DATE])
        ELSE '-'
    END) Roger,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN NAME = 'Larry' THEN CONVERT(varchar, [DATE])
        ELSE '-'
    END) Larry,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN NAME = 'Paul' THEN CONVERT(varchar, [DATE])
        ELSE '-'
    END) Paul,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN NAME = 'Scott' THEN CONVERT(varchar, [DATE])
        ELSE '-'
    END) Scott
FROM
    SourceTable
GROUP BY
    COMPANY;
```

Or just change 'date' to CONVERT(varchar, [DATE]) in what you've got. Since each name is only related to one COMPANY, you don't actually need the GROUP I've shown. That's just my standard technique for 'pivoting' data like that.